# Get lastModified for other files in the same directory as Index.html

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a web page that allows the user to view charts. It is important for the user to know how recent the charts were updated to the site. Next to the charts, I want a label that states the date the chart was updated on the site. The issue is I am only able to get lastModified for the document.
This code gives an undefined error.

Thank you!

```
    var file = 'chart.png'
    document.write(file.lastModified)
/*     document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = document.lastModified; */
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Have you considered retrieving this information on the backend instead?

Comment: Yes, I was able to use a python script. ```   path = 'path'
    mt = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(path)))
    print(mt)